# A expresion of Dirichlet nucleo

Tags: complex-numbers, harmonic-analysis

> Show that
> $$\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^n \cos(kx)=\frac{\sin(nx+\frac{x}{2})}{2\sin\frac{x}{2}}$$

I try the next
$$
\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^n \cos(kx)
 = \frac{1}{2}+\Re \sum_{k=1}^n e^{ikx}
 = \frac{1}{2}+\Re \left[\frac{1-e^{i(n+1)x}}{{1-e^{ix}}}-1\right]
$$
But i not sure to how take to
$$\Re\left[\frac{1-e^{i(n+1)x}}{{1-e^{ix}}}-1\right]$$
Any hint or help i will be very grateful

Comment: For the fractional part, multiply numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator, i.e.$1-e^{-ix}$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/42969